# Correct Regex for strings with text and integers?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to do some math with a string that has text and integers in it, like so:

```
$numberofservings = 8; 
$myarray = ("300g water", "3 tbsp Paprika powder", "2 tbsp Dried oregano", "1 tbsp Dried thyme");

for($a=0; $a < count($myarray); $a++){

  if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $myarray[$a])) {
        $myarray[$a] = str_replace(preg_match('#[0-9]#', $myarray[$a]), preg_match('#[0-9]#', $myarray[$a]) / $numberofservings, $myarray[$a]);
    }

    $newarray[] = "<label>" . $myarray[$a] . "</label>";

}                   


echo implode("<br />", $newarray);
```

When I echo out the new array, its as if the regex only detects some of the values of the array, it gives me the following:

300g water
3 tbsp Paprika powder
2 tbsp Dried oregano
0.25 tbsp Dried thyme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_match` function returns 1 if it has found something. To get the match(es) you have to use the 3rd argument of the function.

Here's a fix for your example:

```
$amount_part = preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $myarray[$a], $matches);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    $myarray[$a] = str_replace($m, $m / $numberofservings, $myarray[$a]);
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!